# AngularJS - huge directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, structure

I have a website that has to display different set of data on a map. The map will always be the same - Some areas with 'onhover' effect and tooltip.

There is about 10 different sets of data.

I created a directive to display the map

**Directive (only draw the map)**

```
angular.module('PluvioradApp.controllers')
    .directive('map', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                    .append("div")
                    .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
                    .append("svg")
                    //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
                    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 500")
                    //class to make it responsive
                    .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);

                var g = svg.append("g");

                //Scale / translate / ...
                var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return (d[0]+50000)/500; })
                     .y(function(d) { return (-d[1]+170000)/500; })
                     .interpolate("linear");

                //Draw map
                var path = g.selectAll('path')
                    .data(data.areas)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("d", function(d){ return lineFunction(d.borders)})
                    .attr("fill", "#D5708B")
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        d3.select(this).style('fill', 'orange');
                        d3.select(this).text(function(d){return "yeah";})
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                        g.selectAll('path').style('fill', '#D5708B');
                    });               


                // zoom and pan
                var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .on("zoom", function() {
                        g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
                        g.selectAll("path")
                            .attr("d", function(d){ return lineFunction(d.borders)});
                    });

                svg.call(zoom);   

            }
        }
    });
```

My idea was to get the data to display from the controller (it comes from an API) and send it to the directive. Inside the above directive I will add a big `switch` or multiple `if` to display the correct data with the correct colors, size,...

I am sure that there is another way to split the work.

For example :

- 1st directive to display the map. It can be reuse multiple time
- 2nd directive to display set 1
- 3rd directive to display set 2

If this is the correct way, how can I achieve this ?

**Additional information**

I have a menu with a dropdown to select which data will be displayed. For the moment, the items redirect to a page containing the map directive above

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your data sets?

Comment: For example, one of the data set will be a list of coordinates, each coordinates containing different values. Those will be markers on the map with labels showing the values.
Another data set is also a list of coordinates with values that will be display as colored pixels on the map (like a cloud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have a folder where you will have a bunch of service, where each service will be one of your data set.
   Set1Service, Set2Service. etc. 
   Each of this will have own logic.
2. Have a factory service which will return one of your service.
   for example:

   (new FactoryService())->get('dataSetItem'); //this will return one of services from point 1.
3. Inject FactoryService in you directive use it.
4. In factory you will have the logic how to parse your data set, to determine what DataSetService you will have to return

This is extensible an easy to use.

All that I described are more related to Strategy and Factory pattern, you can read more about those and this will help you to have more abstract implementation.

```js
angular.module('PluvioradApp.controllers')
    .directive('map', function(factoryService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
              dataSet: '='
            }
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
               //all your code
               var dataSetService = factoryService.get(scope.dataset);
          
               var result = dataSetService.seed(d3);

            }
    }).service('factoryService', function() {
        
        this.get = function(name) {
            var service = null;
            switch (name) {
              case 'set1'
                service = new DataSet1();
                break;
              case 'set2'
                service = new DataSet2();
                break;
            }
            return service;
        }
    });
         
       
                
    function DataSet1() {
            
    }          
    DataSet1.prototype.seed = function(d3) {
       //d3 logic you have access here;
    }
                
    function DataSet2() {
            
    } 
                
    DataSet2.prototype.seed = function(d3) {
       //d3 logic you have access here;
    }
```

Comment: But all my data sets need to be display differently and I cannot use D3.js inside Service. I need a directive for that

Comment: All this Services are just used to prepare you data , you can inject your D3 and use it. You are able to do what you want. This just an abstract view on your problem, the concrete implementation is up to you what data you will pass and what dependency you will have

Comment: Update answer there is abstract example.

Comment: I dont really understand how it should work. I select in the menu the data that I want. The MenuController should call what ? For the moment I am redirecting to a page with my map directive

Comment: @Weedoze can you check no, this is one example how this should look

Comment: @Weedoze, you can pass also the svg or what  you want this just depends on you

Comment: hum ok it seems nice. How can I store DataSet1, DataSet2, ... in other file ? It would be easier to have separeate files

Comment: Yep separated files in some folder this is up to you. I described in the above steps.

Comment: But how can I call another file with simply `new DataSet1();` ? I should only put `function DataSet1()...` in the other file ?

Comment: This will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335526/creating-javascript-objects-from-different-files)

Comment: Okok I will try this in few minutes. If it works well, I will certainly accept it as the answer.

Comment: Where do you find the `scope.dataset` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123222/discussion-between-lkpark-and-weedoze).

Comment: How can I call a service from the DataSet1 file ?

Comment: You can try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259673/how-to-get-angular-service-by-name-programmatically) 
In factory when you create new instance of your services just pass in constructor the $injector and you will be able to access this one.
But I think there a more elegant way to do this, try also [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) at the end is one solution my be will help